# ModelBase, instance, iteration, and order_by

Tags: python, django

There are several different issues here but they are conflated.

I know there is a difference between the class and the instance, but I can’t seem to figure out how to access the latter instead of the former. In the Polls Tutorial 1, they do q=Question(question_text=”What’s up?”) and then do various things with that. But that’s easy. At that point, there is only 1 Question object. Surely I’m not supposed to make variables for every single row in my table, am I? There has to be a better way, but I can’t find it. For example:

```
for a in Articles:
    print a.sections_set.order_by('id')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'ModelBase' object is not iterable
```

And

```
for a in Articles():
    print a.sections_set.order_by('id')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Articles' object is not iterable
```

I’m getting a LOT of type errors like this, not all of them having ‘iterable’. I saw the Loop Like A Native video, so I tried:

```
def __iter__(self):
    for a in Articles:
        print a.sections_set.order_by('id')
__iter__(Articles)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "<console>", line 2, in __iter__
TypeError: 'ModelBase' object is not iterable
```

My ultimate use case here is simply to get the sections to display in order. Currently they show up under their respective article, which is correct*, but in reverse order, which I also can’t seem to fix. I put

```
Sections.objects.order_by('id')
```

In my view

And I put

```
class meta:
    ordering = ['id']
```

on my Sections model. Nothing works.

(*) I also put

```
Articles.objects.order_by('id')
```

In the same view, and that almost worked. It did put the Articles in order, except Article VI comes between Article I and Article II. I went through them all, one at a time, and found that

```
Articles.objects.get(name='Article I')
<Articles: Article I>

A1 = Articles.objects.get(name='Article I')
A1.id
3

Articles.objects.get(name='Article II')
<Articles: Article II>

A2=Articles.objects.get(name='Article II')
A2.id
13
```

(I also don’t get how Article II jumped all the way to id=13 since I put these in at the same time and in order.)

```
A6=Articles.objects.get(name='Article VI')
A6.id
17
```

Last time I checked, 13 was before 17. Does Python/Django have a problem with Roman numerals? If so, then why are all the rest of them now in the right order?

And here’s the killer: my template has no issue at all with the iteration based on the same view code:

```
{% for a in A %}
<h1><li><a href="{% url 'TOC' %}">{{ a.name }} {{ a.popular_name }}</a></li></h1>
    {% for section in a.sections_set.all %}
        <h2><li><a href="{% url 'TOC' %}">{{ section.name }} {{ section.popular_name }}</a></li></h2>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This code works with no issues other than the ones I described above. But this code

```
{% for a in A %}
    <h1><li><a href="{% url 'TOC' %}">{{ a.name }} {{ a.popular_name }}</a></li></h1>
        {% for section in a.sections_set.order_by('id') %}
            <h2><li><a href="{% url 'TOC' %}">{{ section.name }} {{ section.popular_name }}</a></li></h2>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

throws a template syntax error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '('id')' from 'a.sections_set.order_by('id')'
```

Finally, in polls tutorial 3, when they introduce render, they change the code with order_by in it without explanation, from

```
def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

to

```
def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

It would help me understand how to use it if they would a) be consistent and b) explain changes like this.

Answer (score 0):

The second part of your question appears to fully answer the first part: to iterate through all the articles, you use the `objects` manager, ie `Article.objects.all()` to return them all, `Article.objects.order_by('whatever')` to modify the ordering, or `Article.objects.filter(fieldname=whatever)` to query on a certain field value.

For the second part, Django, of course, doesn't know anything at all about Roman numerals: the fact that some of them are in order is a coincidence. And you shouldn't rely on the primary key - `id` - for ordering, either: if you delete and recreate an item, you will get a higher id, since databases generally do not reuse ids. You should add a specific `order` field on your model, and order by that field.

Finally, the template language simply does not permit function calls with parameters, which is why you get that error.